# How do I create simple timed games with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a Whack-a-mole game with raspberry pi. now i'm stuck. i want to let the light light up for 1 sec, in that 1 sec if the user press the button, the light will go off, then score will go up. but if the user missed the light in that 1 sec, score stays the same.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

LED1=18
Butn1=17

GPIO.setup(LED1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Butn1,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

score=0
game=True

while game==True:
    GPIO.output(LED,GPIO.HIGH)
    input_state=GPIO.input(Butn1)
    if input_state==False:
        print('02')
        GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(2)
        score+=1
        print(score)
    elif input_state==True:
        print('03')
        GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(2)
        print (score)
```

Comment: detect button click .... give a point if the light is on ... do not give a point if the light is off

Comment: This is a general programming question, not specific to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Leo, you can ask general programming-related questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

LED1=18
Butn1=17
loopCount = 0

GPIO.setup(LED1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Butn1,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

score=0
game=True

while game==True:
    GPIO.output(LED1, GPIO.HIGH) #first, we turn on the led.
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    # We then run a loop 100 times.
    while loopCount <= 100:
        input_state=GPIO.input(Butn1)
        if input_state == False: # we check to see if the button is pressed
            #if it is, we do the following:
            print('02')
            GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.LOW) #turn the led off
            time.sleep(2) # wait 2 seconds
            score+=1 # increment the score
            print(score) # print the score
            break # and exit the while loop.
        loopCount += 1; # if the button is not pressed, we increment the loop counter,
        time.sleep(0.01) # and wait 10 milliseconds.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
    # the while loop is over. That means that one second has passed, because
    # each loop took 0.01 seconds and it did 100 loops: 0.01 times 100 = 1 second.
    print('03')
    print('button not presed') # the button was not pressed in less than one second
    GPIO.output(LED1,GPIO.LOW) # turn off the led
    time.sleep(2) # wait for 2 seconds.
    print (score) # print the score
    loopCount = 0 # reset the loop counter to 0 for the next loop.
```

ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!  i just wanna know that loopCount<=100 means that the machine will only shine the light 100 times right?

Comment: No @LeoLiu . `loopCount` just keeps track of how many times the code has checked to see if the button has been pressed. Because of the `time.sleep(0.01)` , each loop takes 10 milliseconds. each loop the counter `loopCount` is incremented by 1. So when `loopCount` gets to 100, it means 1 second has gone by: 100 times 10 milliseconds = 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.

Comment: I added some more comments @LeoLiu.

Answer (score 2):

Managing timelines and events is something many Raspberry Pi programmers have to deal with.  The secret is to think in much smaller units of time (not 1 second as you've written). The brute force way of dealing with timelines is to work in repeating units of time, such as 10 milliseconds. You'll find that 10 milliseconds is good for "game latency". Now you can write code that checks the input periodically and responds accordingly. Here is a vanilla "polling loop" that can help you rewrite your program:

```
while game==True:
    time.sleep(0.01); # i.e., the game reacts to anything in 10 millis
    # do something interesting or nothing at all every millisecond
```

Notice that there is one (1) sleep. That is a critical and forces you to consider how to use each 10ms iteration. In other words, make a list of game states (e.g., "waitingForUserInput" or "randomlyWaitingToShineLED") and use that list of states to write your state machine as it executes every 10ms iteration.

A more elegant solution is to use events--look that up later after you get this polling loop working. Event driven code is deceptively easy to write and notoriously hard to debug unless you're following best engineering practices. To write event driven code properly, you would need to fully understand and apply the rigor of test-driven development. From a practical point of view, the polling loop is very simple and maintainable--everything fits on a page and you can always see "what gets executed next". In contrast, with event driven code, order of execution is arbitrarily driven by events. Event driven code is like a nuclear reactor--it can provide great power or kill you.

Comment: Added more text to explain event callback tradeoffs.

Comment: Ok so it means that when i'm doing the testing. I should use time.sleep(0.01) instead of using time.sleep(1).  that's more programmable than using time.sleep(1). thank you very much, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Addon: If you want to do GUI games with timing and stuffs. Have a look at [Kivy](https://kivy.org/)